# exception with method 'to_query' missing

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to install Ruby Bossman, and the following exception happens:

```
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bossman-0.4.1/lib/bossman/boss.rb:10:in `initialize': undefined method `to_query' for #<Hash:0x1010f0800> (NoMethodError)
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bossman-0.4.1/lib/bossman/search.rb:12:in `new'
    from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bossman-0.4.1/lib/bossman/search.rb:12:in `method_missing'
    from es.rb:12
```

any idea? thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem appears because a Hash outside of Rails doesn't have a to_query method.

I changed the code in

```
/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bossman-0.4.1/lib/bossman/boss.rb
```

by changing a line:

```
@uri.query = @options.to_query
```

into this:

```
@uri.query = URI.encode_www_form(@options)
```